# Undefined symbol while building libvault on Mac

Tags: macos, curl, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to build libvault on MacOS.
I have installed curl through "brew install curl" .

I added the following to my .bashrc :

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openldap/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openldap/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig"
```

When I run cmake it passes with :

```
-- Found CURL: /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.75.0/lib/libcurl.dylib (found version "7.75.0")
```

However when I am trying to build it gives me the following error :

```
Linking CXX shared library libvault.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from: ...
```

It seems to me it finds a wrong version of curl.
Could you guys please point me to the right directions how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, linking against curl is disabled by default ...

You need to generate the make files with :

```
cmake -DLINK_CURL=ON
```